# Add custom field (checkbox) in Products Create/Edit page in General Tab in Admin

Tags: admin, custom, products, create-product, product-edit

I want to add a new checkbox labeled as "Featured" in create/edit products page in Magento Admin. This determines if a product is a featured product or not.

These are my requirements :

1. Add "is_featured" column in products table in database
2. In create/edit products page in General Tab in Admin, add a checkbox with label "Featured"
3. When saving the product and the "Featured" checkbox is checked, save the value 1 to "is_featured" column in products table, else save the value 0.

On the front-end side, when querying products via magento collection query, i want to sort products and make Featured product as first on the list. 
Adding is_featured column in db will allow me to sort(descending order) the products easily via is_featured column, sample code :

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                ->setStoreId(0)
                ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id=entity_id', null, 'left')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $category_ids))
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4) // Only catalog, search visiblity
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED))
                ->addAttributeToSort('is_featured', 'DESC')
```

How do i get started or what's the best way to achieve the requirements mentioned above?

**UPDATE :**

The purpose of the requirements above is to sort easily the products via is_featured column

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a product attribute and add the attribute to the attribute set you use. [Here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-attributes-custom-fields) is an official guide to do that.

Comment: creating product attribute is not my best option. I want to add is_featured column in db so when i select all products via collection query, i order them in descending order via is_featured such as this code : $_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->->addAttributeToSort('is_featured', 'DESC')

Comment: By using the attribute/attribute set approach you will be able to do what you want.

Comment: i have updated the question above. Please have a look if your suggestion is still the best approach..

Comment: Yes, it still is.

Comment: great to hear. Can you provide a query which will select all products order by featured descending order? im really lost right now since im new to magento.

Comment: That is another question, if this one is resolved mark it and create a new question with the last comment you posted here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16879/discussion-between-mark-bonnie-vestil-and-mbalparda).